# display table taking extra space on margin top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to create one component that similar to input-group in bootstrap. The reason i was not using the default input-group class of bootstrap is in default I cannot add multiple buttons and input element in input group addon. so i decided to create custom input-group using display-table property but when I use this property some extra space added to top in buttons section.

I need to align the input and counter component in same line.

**HTML Part**

```
 <div class="product-order-form" matAutocompleteOrigin #origin="matAutocompleteOrigin">
    <div class="product-inputGroup tableElem">
        <div class="tableRow">
            <input class="form-control tableCell" type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matAutocompleteConnectedTo]="origin">
            <div class="counter tableCell">
                <div class="counterContainer">
                    <div class="value-button" id="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</div>
                    <input type="text" id="number" value="0" />
                    <div class="value-button" id="increase" value="Increase Value">+</div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tableElem{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.tableRow{
  display:table-row;
  width:100%;
}
.tableCell{
  display:table-cell;
}

.product-order-form{
  height: 30px;
}
.counterContainer {
  width: 150px;
  height:30px;  
}

.value-button{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
}

.value-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}



input#number{
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    width: 50px;   
    float: left;   
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 0.5px solid lightgray;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgray;
}
```

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-boot3-pos)

Comment: Please add codes in your question. In this case external links are not acceptable.

Comment: I added the html and css in my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. `.product-order-form` sets a height of 30px which means it is shorter than some of it's children / siblings. That would cause issues (try adding `overflow:hidden` to see it in action)
2. `.tableCell` has no `vertical-align` which would mean it will position itself at the top o/t component. Try adding `vertical-align: middle` and it should work fine

TL;DR

```
.tableCell[_ngcontent-c2] {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.product-order-form[_ngcontent-c2]{
  height: auto;
}
```

should do the trick :)